# How to escape the "at" (@) symbol when setting a property to a constant string?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

Look at this code:

```
<MyComponent Param1="@SomeValue" />
```

In MyComponent, Param1 will be set to the value of SomeValue variable.
How can i set Param1 to "@SomeValue" String?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap it inside `@(" ")`:

```csharp
<MyComponent Param1="@("@SomeValue")" />
```

...or, in case you ever rename `SomeValue`, play it safe:

```csharp
<MyComponent Param1="@($"@{nameof(SomeValue)}")" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If I undersrtood your Question, you can do it like this

```
<MyComponent Param1="@SomeValue" />

string SomeValue = "@SomeValue";
```